# Django Form is not saving to my db?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am newbie and after reading documentation of django . i made forms but my form is not saving to my db and not showing in my db . please help me i tried so many ways but still its not saving . i have drivers for this purpose i want to register them ..

**Views.py**

```
def driver_form(request):
    args = {}
    template = Template.objects.get(template_default__exact=1)
    template_page = template.template_alias + str("/rentacar/rentacar_driver_form.html")#sir this ?
    return render(request, template_page, args)




def driver_save(request):
    args = {}
    if request.POST:

        driver_firstname = request.POST.get('driver_firstname')
        driver_lastname = request.POST.get('driver_lastname')

        driver_save_form = DriverForm(request.POST)
        if driver_save_form.is_valid():
            new_driver = driver_save_form.save(commit=False)
            new_driver.driver_firstname = driver_firstname
            new_driver.driver_lastname = driver_lastname
            new_driver.save()
            template = Template.objects.get(template_default__exact=1)
            template_page = template.template_alias + str("/rentacar/rentacar_driver_form.html")
            return render(request, template_page, args)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

**rentacar_driver_form**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form method="POST" action="/rentacar/driver-save/">
{% csrf_token %}
<label>
  First Name<br>
  <input type="text" name="driver_firstname" required>
</label>
<br>
<label>
  Last Name<br>
  <input type="text" name="driver_lastname" required>
</label>
<br>

<input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Forms.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django import forms
from rentacar.models import *

class DriverForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BookingApproval
        exclude = (
            'driver_firstname',
            'driver_lastname',
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the code for your DriverForm. I suppose this form subclasses `forms.ModelForm`. Your html isn't aware of your DriverForm at all. You created html inputs, which are not connected to your DriverForm. First you should instantiate your form also for GET request in views.py, pass it to args and adjust returns.

views.py

```
def driver_save(request):
    args = {}
    if request.POST:

        driver_save_form = DriverForm(request.POST)

        if driver_save_form.is_valid():
            new_driver = driver_save_form.save(commit=False)
            new_driver.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        driver_save_form = DriverForm()
        args['driver_save_form'] = driver_save_form
        template = Template.objects.get(template_default__exact=1)
            template_page = template.template_alias + str("/rentacar/rentacar_driver_form.html")
            return render(request, template_page, args)
```

Than you should render the fields of the form you passed via args to the template in html. The simplest way is to render each field as paragraph element with driver_save_form.as_p. I believe you can leave the action attribute of the form empty, since it will post to the same url anyway.

This way when you will visit the relevant url, your form will be instantiated in GET request and than when you will submit it, it will POST back to your view, where POST data will be used to populate your DriverForm and if the form will be valid, the new_driver will be saved to database.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="POST" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}

      {{ driver_save_form.as_p }}

      <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

forms.py

```
class DriverForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BookingApproval
        fields = (
            'driver_firstname',
            'driver_lastname',
        )
```

Comment: still its not saving ?

Comment: @Shko Provide also the code for your DriverForm. Maybe you have problem there.

Comment: ill edit my post. Ill show you my form. Py of driver

Comment: @Shko You are excluding driver_firstname and driver_lastname from the form. You should change exclude word to fields in order to include those two fields to the form.

Comment: Uros include is also not a valid for forms. We can use all and fiields n exclude . and still not working

Comment: Uros can i have your skype . ill show ypu my project

Comment: @Shko Check my edited answer. I added how your forms.py should look like and updated views.py where you don't need some things if you have modelForm.

Comment: @Shko Apart from your unordinary template loading, the code as I wrote it always works for me in identical contexts. A typo in code would throw an error at your side, so I believe if there is no error I can't provide you a better solution.

Comment: uros when ever i write your code and open my template it shows only submit button nothing else

Comment: @Shko If you check the docs you will see that regarding the code everything is as it should be. driver_save_form is passed to args in your case and then the form is rendered in template with {{ driver_save_form.as_p }}. Edit your post with new code. It is impossible to debug without it.